# Автотест выбрасывает NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium, junit

автотест на джаве падает со следующей ошибкой:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.Order_MixedDatePicker__3qiay > div > div > input"}
```

Сам код теста:

```
@Test
    public void test(){
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox", "--headless", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--remote-allow-origins=*");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\dalum\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        String url = "https://qa-scooter.praktikum-services.ru/order";
        driver.get(url);

        AboutRent aboutRent = new AboutRent(driver);
        aboutRent.choseWhenSamokatCome(23);
```

Нужный метод класса AboutRent и переменная whenSamokatCome:

```
private By whenSamokatCome = By.cssSelector("div.Order_MixedDatePicker__3qiay > div > div > input");

public void choseWhenSamokatCome(int dateOfCome) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.findElement(whenSamokatCome));
        driver.findElement(whenSamokatCome).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(whenSamokatCome, "class", "Input_Input__1iN_Z Input_Responsible__1jDKN react-datepicker-ignore-onclickoutside"));
        driver.findElement(whenSamokatCome).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOfAllElements(driver.findElements(calendar)));
        date = By.cssSelector("div.react-datepicker__day.react-datepicker__day--0" + dateOfCome + ".react-datepicker__day--" +
                "keyboard-selected.react-datepicker__day--today.react-datepicker__day--weekend");
        driver.findElement(date).click();
    }
```

Полный текст ошибки следующий:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.Order_MixedDatePicker__3qiay > div > div > input"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=114.0.5735.199)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'MSI', ip: '192.168.0.166', os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '20.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 114.0.5735.199, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f..., userDataDir: C:\Users\dalum\AppData\Loca...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:49873}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 39461ab7bfc4eaeb98e4ba7a7c1c8762
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=div.Order_MixedDatePicker__3qiay > div > div > input}

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:420)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:431)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at pageobject.AboutRent.choseWhenSamokatCome(AboutRent.java:69)
    at Main2.test(Main2.java:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
```

Немного об элементах на веб-странице. Сама структура следующая:

```
<div class="react-datepicker__input-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="* Когда привезти самокат" class="Input_Input__1iN_Z Input_Responsible__1jDKN" value="">
</div>
```

После нажатия на поле она становится такой:

```
<div class="react-datepicker__input-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="* Когда привезти самокат" class="Input_Input__1iN_Z Input_Responsible__1jDKN react-datepicker-ignore-onclickoutside" value="">
</div>
```